# How can you change value this progress bar while another tab is selected?

Tags: swift, storyboard

How can I change the progress of a progress bar while another tab of the TabBarController is selected?
Code:

```
self.RAMBar.progress = Float(response.out)/100
```

Error:

```
2022-04-14 09:51:33.027911+0200 ServiceTOOLS Control[4195:217038] ServiceTOOLS_Control/ViewController.swift:299: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Additional info:
I've only got a ViewController.swift that handles all tabs, this is the erroring code:

```
func parseRAM(){

        guard let url = URL(string: "http://\(hostname):\(port)/STOInfo/Stats/RAM")else{

            return

        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)

        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let body: [String: AnyHashable] = [

            "username": username,

            "password": password,

        ]

        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {data, _, error in

            

            guard let data=data, error == nil else{

                return

            }

            do{

                let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(statsServerInfo.self, from: data)

                print("SUCCESS: \(response)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async{

                    if (self.tabBarController?.tabBar.selectedItem?.tag == 0){

                            self.RAMBar.progress = Float(response.out)/100

                    }

                }

                

            }

            catch{

                print(error)

            }

        }

        task.resume()

    

    

}

@IBOutlet var CPUBar: UIProgressView!

@IBOutlet var RAMBar: UIProgressView!
```

The UIProgressViews are on the first tab. The function automatically runs every 10 seconds with a timer. The error is thrown here: self.RAMBar.progress = Float(response.out)/100
The error happens only if I switch tabs, then I tried putting an if, to check the tab and now, with this code, it happens when, after I switch tabs, I return on the first tab. The exact output is:
SUCCESS: statsServerInfo(ok: true, out: 4)

ServiceTOOLS_Control/ViewController.swift:307: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

2022-04-14 14:52:59.783278+0200 ServiceTOOLS Control[4837:261227] ServiceTOOLS_Control/ViewController.swift:307: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Where do you add the progressBar? I think you should add it to UITabBarController not in UIViewController.

Comment: The progress bar is in the first tab of the TabBarController, the problem is that if you switch tab the timer that refreshes the progress bar every ten seconds crashes with that error @talha_kuet

Comment: please share more code to understand the issue.

Comment: I just need to change a progress bar value while I’m on another tab. If I do with that code, it drops nil, but it works when I’m on the same tab as the progress bar.

Comment: I've added additional information @talha_kuet

Comment: From your given code it seems that you have added a UITabBarController in the UIViewController. If it is yes, then it's wrong way. You have to add the viewController as an item of TabbarController's viewControllers. I am going to put an example as an answer.

Comment: @talha_kuet I have a single ViewController.swift because I need to share variables. You didn't get the question. I have to update the progress bar when I'm on another tab (in the same ViewController.swift!). If I do it when I'm on another time with the normal way (by creating an IBOutlet and modifying the value by assigning self.RAMBar.progress to the value I want) the program crashes and drops an exception, because the Progress Bar isn't on the same tab and it finds nil instead of my Progress bar. If I'm on the right tab the problem doesn't happen and it works perfectly.

Comment: @talha_kuet Now I put an if statement to check if the correct tab is selected, and now the problem occurs only when you return to the correct tab after switching to another.

Comment: this is a wrong way. You can’t use a UITabController in a UIViewController.

Comment: How is it a wrong way if it’s working until this function? I searched on internet to create my tab controller and I did it as they told me. Like on this website: https://www.journaldev.com/10590/ios-tab-bar-controller-with-storyboards. I created multiple Viewcontrollers from the  Interface builder but the file ViewController.swift is a single file. Can you explain me why it’s working until now? Or why it isn’t good doing it? Can you solve ONLY my problem: self.RAMBar.progress becomes nil when I switch tabs? Thank you.@talha_kuet

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use UITabBarController.

I have created two ViewControllers and add a `UIProgressView` in one `UIViewController`. Here is the code of `ViewController.swift` file.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var timer: Timer!
    var progressBarValue: Float = 0
    
    let progressBar: UIProgressView = {
        let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .bar)
        progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        progressView.progress = 0
        progressView.trackTintColor = .lightGray
        progressView.tintColor = .blue
        return progressView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("Main VC")
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateProgressBar), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
        view.addSubview(progressBar)
        
        progressBar.center = view.center
    }
    
    @objc func updateProgressBar() {
        print("Timer called")
        progressBarValue += 0.01
        
        progressBar.progress = progressBarValue
    }
}
```

And this is the code of another ViewController namely `SecondViewController.swift`

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("Second VC")
        view.backgroundColor = .cyan
    }

}
```

Now you have to add these ViewControllers to UITabBarController. I have create a class to programatically add those ViewController. Here is the code of MainTabBarController.swift file

```
import UIKit

class MainTabViewController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let mainVC = ViewController()
        mainVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 1", image: UIImage(systemName: "circle"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill"))
        let secondVC = SecondViewController()
        secondVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Tab 2", image: UIImage(systemName: "square"), selectedImage: UIImage(systemName: "square.fill"))
        
        viewControllers = [mainVC, secondVC]
    }
}
```

Now i set this `MainTabBarController` as `rootViewController` programatically in `SceneDelegate`. It's absolutely ok if you are using Storyboard. Just Set TabBarController as InitialViewController.

```
import UIKit

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window.rootViewController = MainTabViewController()
        self.window = window
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}
```

I have tested this code. The `UIProgressView` in `ViewController` class is updating even if i move to `SecondViewController` in `MainTabBarController`. Hope you get the idea.